# Obtaining an explicit formula for a connection applied to an almost complex structure

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, connections

Let $(M,J)$ be an almost complex manifold and $\nabla$ be a connection on $TM$. I am trying to see how we can obtain an explicit formula for $\nabla_X J$. I know that the way to extend $\nabla$ to a connection on $T^*M$ is by defining for $\alpha \in \Gamma(T^*M)$, $\nabla_X(\alpha)(Y):= X(\alpha(Y)) - \alpha(\nabla_X Y)$, and on $T^*M \otimes TM$ we can extend $\nabla$ to $\nabla_X (\alpha \otimes Y):= (\nabla_X \alpha) \otimes Y + \alpha \otimes (\nabla_X Y)$.

Further, $J \in \Gamma(\textrm{End}(TM))$, so actually $J \in \Gamma(T^*M \otimes TM)$. But I can't see how to deduce from the above extensions an actual formula for $\nabla_X J(\alpha \otimes Y)$ in terms of just $J, \alpha, \nabla_X Y, X, Y$.

One of the problems with this is that I don't know how to write $J$ as an element in $T^*M \otimes TM$ except in local coordinates, where things get ugly. Is there any way to avoid local coordinates? How would a derivation of an expression for $\nabla_X J$ go in any case?

Answer (score 0):

for any vector field $Y$ and covector field $\alpha$, $\alpha(J(Y))$ is a smooth function. Since the directional derivative $\nabla_X$  commutes with contraction, we have :
\begin{align}
X(\alpha(J(Y)) &= \nabla_X(\alpha(J(Y))) \\
&= (\nabla_X \alpha) (J(Y)) + \alpha((\nabla_XJ)(Y)) + \alpha(J(\nabla_XY)) 
\end{align}
Therefore $\nabla_X J$ is the section of $\operatorname{End}(TM)$ such that :
$$\alpha((\nabla_XJ)(Y))  = X(\alpha(J(Y)) - (\nabla_X \alpha) (J(Y)) - \alpha(J(\nabla_XY)) $$

Comment: How do you arrive at $\nabla_X (\alpha(J(Y)) = (\nabla_X \alpha) (J(Y)) + \alpha( (\nabla_XJ)(Y)) + \alpha(J(\nabla_X Y))$?
By my definition, $(\nabla_X \alpha)(J(Y)) = \nabla_X(\alpha(J(Y))) - \alpha(\nabla_X (JY))$, so the question is then why $\alpha(\nabla_X(J(Y)) ) = \alpha(\nabla_X J(Y)) + \alpha(J (\nabla_XY))$? Since this is for any $\alpha$, equivalently the question is why
$\nabla_X (J(Y)) = (\nabla_X J)(Y) + J(\nabla_X Y)$?